# Why does calling [-1] of a python list give this output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This may be a theoretical question, but please bear with me. Why does this Python code produce this output?

```py
content = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', '\n.']
print(content[-1])
```

The output is:

```py
.
```

Why does the `.` come? Why isn't there an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python lists can be indexed by negative numbers, with -1 referring to the last element, -2 referring to the second to last element, and so on.

Specifically for this example, `content[-1]` refers to `'\n.'`. The character `'\n'` is a whitespace character that creates a new line. Thus, your print statement outputs a new line followed by the period.

Comment: Yes, but there is no ```.``` item in my list. Why is that the output?

Comment: The last item in your list is `'\n.'`, this is a newline followed by a dot.

Comment: Try adding a print("----") before your print statement. You should see an empty line between ---- and the dot